# Jackson Databind Objectmapper 2.10 - not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

I am trying to update jackson library from 2.9.x to 2.11.x. noticed that there are some changes in 2.10 because of which, the below is not working.

```
class Customer {

@JsonProperty("value")
String Value;

@JsonIgnore
String status;

// getters and setters
}


class CustomerResponse {

@JsonProperty
String id;

@JsonProperty
Customer customer;

}

Class Response {


@JsonProperty
CustomerResponse response;

}
    Response val = getReturn();

    ObjectMapper obm = new ObjectMapper();
CustomerResponse scc= obm.convertValue(val.getCustomerResponse(), new TypeReference<CustomerResponse>(){});
  
String statusFromCustomer = scc.getCustomer().getStatus();
```

The value of statusFromCustomer while using Jackson 2.9.x is working as expected but in 2.10 it is returning null.

Can this be because of @JsonIgnore? if it is, then how did it work in 2.9.x versions?

Comment: Please add more details: `SomeCustomClass` class and related classes. Also provide `JSON` payload.

Comment: Try adding the property name as annotation metadata to JsonProperty annotation of affected field   eg . :  @JsonProperty("statusFromCustomer").

Comment: Post the JSON..